# Mechanism to rename a bunch of files from BIG5 to Unicode in a batch on Windows

Tags: command-line, powershell, unicode

I'm looking for a method to rename a bunch of files from BIG5 to Unicode in a batch on Windows.

NOTE: BIG5 is a special Chinese encoding.

Comment: What file system are these files saved in? Open My Computer, right-click the drive the files are on, choose Properties, then tell us what appears after "File system:".

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename a file from one encoding to another. On NTFS, filenames are handled as native Unicode strings and so do not have any byte-encoding associated with them. (Internally, they are stored in the UTF-16LE encoding, but that's an implementation detail.)

Do you mean the filenames are rendering wrong at the moment due to a previous encoding misinterpretation? If so, what do they look like at the moment?